# Using QGIS Raster Calculator with two different rasters

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I have several maps like this one:

[image: Soil Use]

And with the proximity tool and a coastline shapefile I made this output, representing the distance to shoreline:

[image: Distance to Shoreline]

Now, I want to combine both using the Raster Calculator. However, everytime that I make an operation, the output is just NaN.

Do you have any hint on why is that?

---

Solved! Both maps had different projections and the "on the fly reprojection" was activated.

Comment: You are using only Raster Calculator within the toolboxes or you ar adding something more? can you write down your sintaxis in the Raster Calculator?

Comment: I'm only using the Raster Calculator normally.
This for example, doesn't work:
"Revestimento de Solo@1"*(1/28-0.665*("dist_linha_costa_metros_area_restrita@1"-100)/(4900*22))

Comment: actually, the distance to shoreline layer don't work with any calculations from Raster Calculator... even "dist_linha_costa_metros_area_restrita@1"-100 does not work

Comment: So how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a guess but this often happens when the two rasters in different projections.

Try verifying that both share the same coordinate systems.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the values in your raster, if your operation makes sense? Did you double-check syntax of your expression?

I am always confused about syntax, because I just use raster calculator once in a while. 
I can just speak from an arcGIS point of view, but there you have a model builder and another tool from toolbox, I think it is called Single Output Map Algebra. Both allow you to just add or subtract a constant to/from your raster, like you did.

Maybe you have similar tools in QGIS you can use alternatively, to prove correctness of our approach, besides syntax? I personally do prefer those over raster calculator.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the filename is the problem. 1. Too long 2. contains the "@" character.

Comment: When you already have used the raster calculator in QGIS, you know the "@1" stands for the raster band 1.

Answer (score 0):

Also I had a problem when selecting the extent. QGIS at the moment only updates to the correct extent after you choose the output file.

With an invalid extent I was only obtaining NaN