# If statement using QgsRasterCalculator?

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator

In the sequence of my previous question ([Can't use Raster Calculator with two different rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130218/cant-use-raster-calculator-with-two-different-rasters)), I am stuck again in my project.

With my source rasters, I created 3 different outputs using the following code:

```
calc100 = QgsRasterCalculator('aa@1*(1/28) + ao@1*(2/28) + am@1*(1/28) + ct@1*(6/28) + ln@1*(6/28) + ea@1*(2/28) + gl@1*(6/28) + gm@1*(2/28) + rs@1*(2/28)', 'D:/maps/z100.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc100.processCalculation()

calc100to5000 = QgsRasterCalculator('ln@1 * (6/28+0.665*(d@1-100)/4900) + ct@1 * (6/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*6/(4900*22)) + gl@1 * (6/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*6/(4900*22)) + gm@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + rs@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + ao@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + ea@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + am@1 * (1/28-0.665*(d@1-100)/(4900*22)) + aa@1 * (1/28-0.665*(d@1-100)/(4900*22))', 'D:/maps/z100to5000.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc100to5000.processCalculation()

calc5000 = QgsRasterCalculator('ln@1 * 0.879 + ct@1 * 0.033 + gl@1 * 0.033 + gm@1 * 0.011 + rs@1 * 0.011 + ao@1 * 0.011 + ea@1 * 0.011 + am@1 * 0.005 + aa@1 * 0.005', 'D:/maps/z5000.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc5000.processCalculation()
```

However, I just want to create one single output raster. I have one raster with the distance to shoreline at each point, and I was thinking if it's possible to insert an if statement to identify the value in that raster and use the respective formula to the pixel in question, something like this:

```
if d@1 < 100:
calc100 = QgsRasterCalculator('aa@1*(1/28) + ao@1*(2/28) + am@1*(1/28) + ct@1*(6/28) + ln@1*(6/28) + ea@1*(2/28) + gl@1*(6/28) + gm@1*(2/28) + rs@1*(2/28)', 'D:/maps/z100.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc100.processCalculation()

if d@1 >= 100 and d@1 <= 5000:    
calc100to5000 = QgsRasterCalculator('ln@1 * (6/28+0.665*(d@1-100)/4900) + ct@1 * (6/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*6/(4900*22)) + gl@1 * (6/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*6/(4900*22)) + gm@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + rs@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + ao@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + ea@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + am@1 * (1/28-0.665*(d@1-100)/(4900*22)) + aa@1 * (1/28-0.665*(d@1-100)/(4900*22))', 'D:/maps/z100to5000.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc100to5000.processCalculation()

if d@1 > 5000:    
calc5000 = QgsRasterCalculator('ln@1 * 0.879 + ct@1 * 0.033 + gl@1 * 0.033 + gm@1 * 0.011 + rs@1 * 0.011 + ao@1 * 0.011 + ea@1 * 0.011 + am@1 * 0.005 + aa@1 * 0.005', 'D:/maps/z5000.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc5000.processCalculation()
```

If it's not possible, could you recommend a viable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an alternative answer to my problem, so I think I should share it with anyone interested.

So, instead of trying to find a "if" function that worked, I created masks for each function, in order to only give results for the areas that I wanted to and 0 for the other zones.

```
calc100 = QgsRasterCalculator('(d@1 < 100)*(aa@1*(1/28) + ao@1*(2/28) + am@1*(1/28) + ct@1*(6/28) + ln@1*(6/28) + ea@1*(2/28) + gl@1*(6/28) + gm@1*(2/28) + rs@1*(2/28))', 'D:/maps/z100.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc100.processCalculation()

calc100to5000 = QgsRasterCalculator('(d@1 >= 100 AND d@1<=5000)*(ln@1 * (6/28+0.665*(d@1-100)/4900) + ct@1 * (6/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*6/(4900*22)) + gl@1 * (6/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*6/(4900*22)) + gm@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + rs@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + ao@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + ea@1 * (2/28-0.665*(d@1-100)*2/(4900*22)) + am@1 * (1/28-0.665*(d@1-100)/(4900*22)) + aa@1 * (1/28-0.665*(d@1-100)/(4900*22)))', 'D:/maps/z100to5000.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc100to5000.processCalculation()

calc5000 = QgsRasterCalculator('(d@1 > 5000)*(ln@1 * 0.879 + ct@1 * 0.033 + gl@1 * 0.033 + gm@1 * 0.011 + rs@1 * 0.011 + ao@1 * 0.011 + ea@1 * 0.011 + am@1 * 0.005 + aa@1 * 0.005)', 'D:/maps/z5000.tif', 'GTiff', aco_ant.extent(), aco_ant.width(), aco_ant.height(), entries)
calc5000.processCalculation()
```

Then, I only had to sum all the maps using the QgsRasterCalculator in the same way as above, since the maps with the mask don't overlap each others:

```
vuln = QgsRasterCalculator('v100@1 + v100to5000@1 + v5000@1', 'D:/maps/vuln.tif', 'GTiff', z100.extent(), z100.width(), z100.height(), entries)
vuln.processCalculation()
```

Thanks to all,
Pedro